# Apparently I don't know how exp:channel:entries status and limit work together

Tags: channel-entries, status, parameters

I want to grab the 1 most recent entry and display it big. Then I want to grab the next most 6 recent entries and display them small.

So:
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1"} and {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="6" offset="1"}

The problem is if my most recent blog entry is closed. Then nothing big shows up and the small items start at the 2 blog entry (the closed entry is offset). I get the same results if I add status="open".

All this time I had assumed exp:channel:entries would consider the status before applying the rest of the params, especially limit and offset. Since status param defaults to open, obviously I want to limit to the open entries.

Am I wrong? Is it something new with v2.8.1? How did you think it worked?

Comment: I haven't experimented much with the offset parameter, but to do what you want (first entry big, next 6 small) you could use the {if count == 1 }{/if} conditional.

Comment: @positlux please post that as an answer

Comment: I was going to post this as answer, but the OP actually asked about the behavior of the status/limit/offset parameters -- to which I do not actually know the answer to.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a basic setup for what you're trying to achieve, with the class `.biggie` representing the markup for making your entry big, and the absence of that class indicating a "normal" representation of your remaining entires.

***NOTE:*** Since the default order for channel entry output is reverse date order (newest first) you do not need to specify any order or sort. If you wanted to sort/order by a different criteria, you would simply add that to the opening parameters.

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="blog"
  limit="7"
}

  {if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}

  {if count == "1"}
    <h2 class="biggie">{title}</h2>
    <p class="biggie">{body}</p>

  {if:else}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{body}</p>
  {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```